# Android: Compute properties after GSON deserialization finished

Tags: android, gson, deserialization, pojo

In one of my apps I have a generic Volley web service which I use to load data from our servers and deserialize them sing GSON like so:

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        T parsedJson = mGson.fromJson(json, mType);
        return Response.success(parsedJson, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Now one of the objects I'm deserializing is a little bit *special* since its json model contains of two lists but in code I need a dictionary where ids of the first lists objects are the keys and arrays of the second lists objects are the values.

I also need to sort the two lists after they have been deserialized. (I begged our backend devs to do the sorting and deliver me a proper json model but they refuse to do that, don't ask me why...).

Anyways, now I need a way to do the sorting as well as the calculation of the properties.

In iOS I'm using SwiftyJson which is not really the automatic JSON deserialization you'd get from GSON but there I can calculate and sort the necessary fields in the background thread where I "deserialize" the obejcts.

On Android though, I have this generic function and therefore no clue which object I'm currently deserializing and as far as I'm concerned, GSON uses a default constructor and writes to the fields directly rather than using setters.

So now I'm stuck. I wonder when the best situation would be to calculate my fields. I thought about these ways:

1. Add a transient boolean to check if I already sorted the lists. When accessing the getter for the lists, the first time it is false so I know I have to sort. I sort the list, store the sorted list back and then return it. For the calculated dictionary, I'd just had to check if its null and if so, calculate it
2. Implement some sort of `PostDeserializable` interface with a single method. In the generic web service, I could check if the `T parsedJson` is an instance of that interface and if so, call the method on it.

The later would had the advantage that it would run in the background but I also had to remember that interface (which might be problematic for new developers who don't know about it). The first however could have an impact since it most likely would run in the UI thread.

I wonder if there is a default way in GSON to execute some post serialization method, maybe via annotations? Hope you can help me find the best way with the least amount of custom code.

Comment: Does it fit your needs: https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/interceptors ?

Comment: this looks exactly like what I think I would need. Unfortunately this is not available via gradle so I guess I could just use my own interface so I don't have all the overhead of the other gson-extras

Comment: Yep, you're right, this is just gson-extras and this is not published as an artifact globally. You can just borrow that code and modify it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently there is no default way of doing it. Though there is a similar interface to the one I suggested in my original post but it is only available in the gson-extras which are not published via maven so one can not simply include it in the gradle file. Instead, one would have to manually download it and keep it up to date.

For me that seems to be unnecessary work and including the whole gson-extras for just this one interface seems to be a little bit over the top. After testing both of my approaches, I think I will stick with the interface solution I suggested.

I changed my JSON volley base request (from which all of my JSON requests inherit) to the following:

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        T parsedJson = mGson.fromJson(json, mType);

        if (parsedJson instanceof PostDeserializable) {
            PostDeserializable postDeserializable = (PostDeserializable) parsedJson;
            postDeserializable.postDeserialization();
        }

        if (parsedJson instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] array = (Object[]) parsedJson;
            for(Object value : array) {
                if (value instanceof PostDeserializable) {
                    PostDeserializable postDeserializable = (PostDeserializable) value;
                    postDeserializable.postDeserialization();
                }
            }
        }

        return Response.success(parsedJson, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

The PostSerializable interface looks pretty simple as well:

```
public interface PostDeserializable {
    void postDeserialization();
}
```

And to use it, all I have to do is to implement it on my model POJOs. Notice that I check if the `T parsedJson` itself is an instance of my interface as well as I check if it is an array and if so, if the objects in the array are of that type.

For me that is enough because I only every have the need for a PostSerializable if the top level object is an instance of it or if the top level object is an array of PostSerializables.

**This is not a general solution because it does not cover cases, where the PostSerializable is for example in the 2nd level of another model.**

In such a case, I think it would definitely make sense to use gson-extras.